# ubuntu 18.04 5 progress dots remain in center of screen

Tags: 18.04

I updated to Ubuntu 18.04 from 17.10 and the update seemed to go well but now when I boot up, the progress dots just seem to keep cycling across the center of my screen.

Comment: What shows up when you press Esc while that happens?

Comment: Nothing changes